# Most negative and most positive value for proton chemical shifts

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

What are the most negative and the most positive values for proton chemical shifts recorded till present?

Comment: I suspect the most positive values can be found in superacidic media such as $\ce{HF - SbF5}$, which contain extremely poorly solvated, essentially bare $\ce{H^+}$ ions.

Comment: What are the values?

Comment: It's been ages, but I stumbled on [this article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ic049825q) at random, showing a number of very closely related compounds with proton chemical shifts that vary from -58 ppm to +140 ppm! There are also some amusing carbon-13 shifts to be had.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if the following two examples present the "largest" upfield and downfield proton-nmr chemical shifts, but I suspect they're in the running.  The dihydropyrene dianion example has 16 pi electrons

[image]

delocalized around the periphery of the pyrene frame. It fits the 4n rule with n=4, so it is antiaromatic.  The [16]-annulene dianion has 18 pi electrons and fits the 4n+2 rule with n=4, so it is aromatic.  Note how the direction of the [ring current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromatic_ring_current) reverses between antiaromatic (paramagnetic current) and aromatic (diamagnetic current) systems.  More intesting proton chemical shifts can be found in this [compilation](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/05-hmr-02-delta.htm).

**Edit**

Guilty of thinking organic.  If we're including inorganic proton shifts, then how about [IrHCl2(PMe(t-Bu)2)2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_metal_hydride) which has a chemical shift of -50.5!

Comment: Thanks. I examined the link you posted. I see the rhodium-pentacyano-hydride has around -10 ppm and that theoretically, a naked proton would have a chemical shift of 40 ppm (which is probably the maximum possible). So I will take the most negative shift to be -10 ppm, and the most positive "measured" to be 21.24 ppm. If anyone finds some even more extreme values, I would like to see them.